# Error in building project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Freshly Installed **Android Studio** and started new android project.
When tried to run it. Got this error from Gradle

```
Error:Could not open initscript class cache for initialization script 'C:\Users\Dexter\AppData\Local\Temp\asLocalRepo10.gradle' (C:\Users\Dexter\.gradle\caches\2.2.1\scripts\asLocalRepo10_d10e66d3o7exs19wwq4uj2zhv\InitScript\initscript).
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Dexter\.gradle\caches\2.2.1\scripts\asLocalRepo10_d10e66d3o7exs19wwq4uj2zhv\InitScript\initscript\cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

I have tried to rebuild the project and also tried to delete `.gradle` folder but nothing worked.

Comment: I just wanted to comment because I got the same error message, and I know the process of how it happend. (1) Run app by IDE on a phone (2) Windows 8.1 Blue screens (3) Windows restarts, but has to scan the disk for problems (4) Windows starts, but quickly becomes unresponsive, especially opening Android Studio (moving the mouse works, clicking does not work, except to click on the taskbar to minimize windows only) (5) Forced to Restore windows to a checkpoint a few days ago (6) Got the same error message as the OP

Comment: I am getting this error too frequently, it wasn't there before, after some time of using Android Studio it started to appear. Deleting the lock file is a temporary solution and not a permenant solution that prevents this error from appearing. For this reason i am starting a bounty

Comment: @EnesBattal You will have to explain your situation more. I would believe that if you keep on getting this error, then you have a more serious error on your hand, and you might have to reinstall Android Studio. I think for most people, the answers below are the permanent solution. State your issues more thoroughly and we can help you

Comment: @EnesBattal I updated my answer...let me know if it works. Also, for the lock file, are you 100% certain you deleted the right one? There are a lot of   `asLocalRepo...` files. If you delete the wrong one, then you will have the issues you have stated

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the actual answer should find out why the lock file is not removed automatically and solves it. But right now, I am ok for a solution that would delete the lock file at every `build` of `Android Studio`, not manually starting the .bat file. If the bat file can be run at beginning of every build automatically, that would be fine.

Comment: If you have to run a .bat file at every run, then you have a bigger problem...you are putting bandages on a deep wound. Android Studio is designed to not have to do what you are doing....you probably have a corrupt IDE. Did you try to see if a new install works? Again, you can have multiple installs of Android Studio on your machine....so this is testable. Give us information on your Android Studio installation...you have not given us any information to solve your issue

Comment: Why do you feel that the correct solution is to have a non-AS solution that will automatically delete these lock files? You should answer that question, but anyway, as an addition, don't you think that if AS is not deleting them, that there is some underlining issue with your installation of the IDE? For me, I had a BSOD while using AS. This caused corruption in my AS where it was completely unusable, but doing my below answer fixed it. It didn't fix your installation, but I can guarantee that a new installation will fix your issues 100%. Guaranteed.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm having the same problem and deleting just the cache.properties.lock is not enough.

The solution, as pointed before, is deleting the cache.properties.lock file, but not only in the folder pointed by Android Studio. I needed to remove every lock file inside .gradle\caches\VERSION.

So, I created a small .bat file with this:

```
del /s cache.properties.lock
```

Add this file to .gradle\caches\VERSION\ and run it. My Android Studio stopped complaining afterwards.

Hope it helps!

Comment: how to automate this so that it doesn't complain later again?

Comment: gradle is such crap.. disappointed that Google makes it the default build system

Answer (score 9):

### Error Message

```
Error:Could not open initscript class cache for initialization script 
    'C:\Users\Dexter\AppData\Local\Temp\asLocalRepo10.gradle' 
    (C:\Users\Dexter\.gradle\caches\2.2.1\scripts\asLocalRepo10_d10e66d3o7exs19wwq4uj2zhv
    \InitScript\initscript)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Dexter\.gradle\caches\2.2.1\scripts\
    asLocalRepo10_d10e66d3o7exs19wwq4uj2zhv\InitScript\initscript\cache.properties 
    (The system cannot find the file specified)`
```

The most important parts of this error message are

```
- Could not open initscript class cache
- asLocalRepo10_d10e66d3o7exs19wwq4uj2zhv
```

### So

- Let `_XXX_    = asLocalRepo10_d10e66d3o7exs19wwq4uj2zhv`
- Let `_USER_   = Dexter`
- Let `_GRADLE_ = 2.2.1`

### Solution

**Delete**
`C:\Users\_USER_\.gradle\caches\_GRADLE_\scripts\_XXX_\InitScript\initscript\cache.properties.lock`

### Does this not work?

Then you have to find out the root solution. This is probably due to a corrupt IDE. Try installing another copy of Android Studio on your system.

Note: You can have multiple copies of Android Studio on your system. [Here is the latest Preview](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/1-4-preview-3). If you check the notes on the page, you can see what you need to do to install a new version on AS.

Let us know if this works...if not, we can try to elimate other possible issues

Answer (score 8):

go to location

`".gradle\caches\2.0\scripts\build_7l4t45nbnsvdcl79ol8u0beli4\ProjectScript"`

delete cache.properties.lock file

Comment: or you can just remove scripts folder in c:/users/<user>/.gradle/caches/2.4 or latest your using inside that folder , remove scripts folder

Answer (score 5):

I am also getting the same error.
So what I did is this that I cleared the **Temp folder** (If you don't know where it is then just hit **Window+R** and enter **%temp%** OR you can type %temp% in address bar too in File Explorer).
Now again run the project, it should run fine.
I don't know the permanent solution but what I am telling it works for me.
If anyone do know the permanent fix then please share that.

Comment: this helps me but not completely, I just deleted a few files from the directory which showing me the error in my case it was "C:/Windows/TEMP"  and I have deleted all the file which belongs to android studio.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was the roaming profile issue. Gradle Sync failed every time I switched networks from work to home. Although I was able to access the network drives by connecting with VPN, still it used to give this error. I had to move the Gradle Service Directory Path to a different location that wasn't dependent on the network.

You can do this in AS 1.4 by going to File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle > Service Directory Path. Screen shot below:

[image]

You can also add GRADLE_USER_HOME environment variable with the same value of the location for making it a default for every project (http://blog.james-carr.org/2011/05/04/setting-gradle-cache-to-a-common-location/). You may refer to the following page for more info on moving Android related stuff to different locations: http://www.littlecpu.com/android-studio-c-drive

Answer (score 2):

*File* -> *Invalidate Cache / Restart* worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I have deleted .gradle folder and clean the project on re run the project was working fine.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues. For me the solution was simply to delete all files inside the folder C:\Users\Dexter.gradle\caches\2.2.1\scripts\ Also i removed VCS configuration from android studio. No need to install new Android Studio to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. just restart your Gradle and then clean your project. i hope this help

Answer (score 0):

For Me Issue get resolved by giving permission

1. For window 
   C:\Users
   Right click on Users >> Click on Security Tab >> Add Group and username there
   as for example SYSTEm, your comany mail id
2. For Linux

provide 777 permission for .android and .gradle folder by using 
sudo chmod 777 -R .android/ 
sudo chmod 777 -R .gradle/