# could not open initscript class cache for initialization script

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image]

> Error:Could not open initscript class cache for initialization script 'C:\Users\Avishek\AppData\Local\Temp\asLocalRepo14.gradle' (C:\Users\Avishek.gradle\caches\2.2.1\scripts\asLocalRepo14_dkwbdtenxxgt2q2wfe57wj30b\InitScript\initscript).
>    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Avishek.gradle\caches\2.2.1\scripts\asLocalRepo14_dkwbdtenxxgt2q2wfe57wj30b\InitScript\initscript\cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)

This error gives when I want to rebuild a project or clean project or run project.

Please someone help me...Thank you...

Answer (score 34):

Don't use Gradle with a fresh version of JDK. It may not support it. In my case, downgrading JDK solved the issue.

Comment: This Answer should be accepted! It worked for me

Comment: Same. Upvoting . The problem is indeed occuring only with JDK 17 for me, downgrading to JDK 15 worked . I got it for a fresh compose-desktop app created with IntelliJ Idea.

Answer (score 8):

You should delete "scripts" folder from "C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\2.4\" via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121034/android-studio-gradle-refresh-failed-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified) answer. Then refresh gradle from Android Studio. This worked for me.

Comment: I delete the "2.2.1" from "C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\". Then I restart the Android Studio. That's works for me...

Answer (score 2):

**2022 New Answer for Kotlin base projects**

1. Open IntelliJ IDEA CE
2. Click **Create New Project** or **File/New/Project**

**Important !!!**

3. Select ***Kotlin*** from left side of window.
4. Select ***IntelliJ*** in Build System.
5. Click Next.
6. Done. You will not have this error when you run your Kotlin file in the IDE.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me, I think there is a problem with the Graddle Build System esp if you are using JDK Version 20.

Answer (score 1):

You may have opened Android Studio twice. In that case close one of the instances and click on Try Again or Synchronize Gradle, or restart Android Studio. It is because the gradle build was not completed and other dependencies like classpath did not initialize at startup.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and followed these steps to correct the error.

- Step 1 : Check your gradle JDK Version by going to ***Settings ->
  Build,Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Gradle JDK***
- Step 2 : Check the gradle JDK version that is compatible with your Java version from [this link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html)
- Step 3 : Next navigate to **`gradle-wrapper.properties`**
- Step 4 : On **`distributionUrl`** change the gradle version according to
  your java version

For instance, I was using `JDK 20 Gradle Version` but had `8.0 on distributionUrl`.
[image]

I changed it to the matching **`8.3`** and then syched the project and the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

You should check android studio power save menu in file. If it was previously  selected, then it should be unselected the power save mode in android studio in file menu. I hope it will be worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have deleted .gradle folder and clean the project on re run the project was working fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Close the android studio
2. Delete this file from your pc **C:\Users\Avishek\AppData\Local\Temp\asLocalRepo14.gradle**
3. Delete folder from your pc **C:\Users\Avishek.gradle\caches\2.2.1**
4. Your app in **.gradle** and **.idea** file is also delete
5. And start your android studio

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade gradle to the latest version by modifying the url in gradle-wrapper.properties