# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'. java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: android

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2531Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72531Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2531Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72531Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2531Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2531Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2531Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2531Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2531Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42531Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2531Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTransition2531Library
:app:prepareComGithubPaolorotoloAppintro400Library
:app:prepareComGithubRey5137Material124Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1101Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1101Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1101Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics1101Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl1101Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAppindexing1101Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon1101Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCore1101Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCrash1101Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid1101Library
:app:prepareComMcxiaokeVolleyLibraryAar100Library
:app:prepareComMikhaellopezCircularimageview302Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\....\app\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\   \BuildConfig.java (The system cannot find the path specified)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.668 secs
```

Unable to understand what went wrong. Anybody have any pointers if I can see? 
What I've tried so far is changed the version of support libs(currently using 25.3.1) and project configurations in app's build.gradle. Below is my build.gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.some.package"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 5
    versionName "5.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.4'
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I've tried to build same version which I've downloaded from version control but still giving me same error. I've tried to build some different project and it is successfully build.

Anybody faced this previously if yes how did you solved this? Any pointer where should I look?

Thanks in advance.
- Rahul

Comment: Please post your gradle file.

Comment: Clean and rebuild

Comment: Tried so but still failed to build. I also tried this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121034/android-studio-gradle-refresh-failed-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified