# Conflicts and Errors in android studio after merging the code, even when the files have not been changed

Tags: java, android, git, android-studio, android-emulator

I am new to android studio but have experience with Git. Every time I try to merge a pull request that a co-developer has made I get conflicts even when I have not made any changes to my code. The errors are different each time but the most common one is **The system cannot find the path specified**.

here is the list of files that have conflicts:

1. build_file_checksums.ser
2. buildOutputCleanup.lock
3. executionHistory.bin
4. executionHistory.lock
5. fileHashes.bin
6. fileHashes.lock
7. gradle_models.ser
8. javaCompile.lock

sometimes there are more files. I click on **Accept Theirs** for all the files and then I get build errors.

Please Note that I use an emulator where as my co-developer connects his phone with USB. I have to clear cache and sometimes delete scripts file as mentioned here [android studio gradle refresh failed (The system cannot find the file specified)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121034/android-studio-gradle-refresh-failed-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified/32413895) . This trick just worked once. I clean the project and **invalidate cache and restart**. This also worked couple of times. Many times I had to install a new emulator to solve this issue.

Here are few error message examples:

x:\AndroidProject12\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-pt\values-pt.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)

x:\AndroidProject12\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\android\arch\lifecycle\livedata\core\R.java

x:\AndroidProject12\build\intermediates\instant_run_split_apk_resources\debug\instantRunSplitApkResourcesDebug\out\slice_3\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)

Thank You

Comment: Except for source codes, try adding these unwanted files(If they don't make sense) to gitignore.

Comment: I added all the files to git ignore but still I am facing errors, there were some extra files this time, total 12.