# Gradle sync error on android studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I run my project gives "System does not find path specified" error.I did system restore recently also

Gradle "Game" project refresh failed from gradle sync

```
Error:C:\Users\xx\.gradle\caches\2.2.1\scripts\settings_atmw4hxm6c97zkg2oz5zwybdi\SettingsScript\buildscript\cache.properties (System does not find path specified)
```

Comment: Please check the following link for solve this error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28581211/how-to-project-clean-in-android-studio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in building project in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30749042/error-in-building-project-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean project
Build->Clean

Comment: No. Cleaning did not work. I tried cleaning and it shows the same error.