# Android Studio: Failed to configure project

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I am unable to run my app due to the error below. When I try to clean or rebuild the project, I still get the same error.

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
Failed to create directory '/home/sukumar/.gradle/caches/3.3/scripts-remapped/build_9z8fmh3h5n5zou3vkratrypnt/2nngi2eh7ayb88x5py6bqkz9r/cp_proj1efd45104ffa2d33563b85b9edda76e3'
```

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you have writing permissions for that folder.

Comment: I do have read and write permission to .gradle folder

Comment: check your free space in computer

Comment: @alicanozkara 110GB

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30749042/error-in-building-project-in-android-studio it may help you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I closed android studio and then deleted the `.gradle` folder. Then I reopened android studio and tried to open the project. This made the project rebuild the `.gradle` folder.  This got rid of the problem.