# How to pick a video from gallery in the newest API?

Tags: android, video, gallery

I'm trying to get the path of a video in the gallery but the URI give me something like "/document/video:xxxx". When i use getPath() i get always null.

I have set up a FileProvider and granted all permissions but nothing works.

```
    //Start intent

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("video/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Video"), 1);

    //Turn URI to Path

    String getPath(Uri uri) {

    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        // HERE YOU WILL GET A NULLPOINTER IF CURSOR IS NULL. THIS CAN BE, IF YOU USED OI FILE MANAGER FOR PICKING THE MEDIA
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    }
```

Comment: The subject of your post has nothing to do with the problem described in your post. Please adapt.

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to pick a video from the gallery:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,   MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```

Read [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore) for more information on `intents` and `MediaStore`.

Comment: I get the correct path but it gives me `java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20191105_203230.mp4`

Comment: please add storage dependecy permission

Comment: Please follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164357/android-update-causing-error-errorjava-nio-file-accessdeniedexception-home-p
       it may helps you.

Answer (score 0):

add below dependency in build.gradle(App):

```
implementation 'com.droidninja:filepicker:2.2.0'
```

set widget clicklistener and create array imgbase64 of File:

```
private var imageBase64 = ArrayList<File>()

imgVideo.setOnClickListener {
            val intent1 = Intent(this, VideoPickActivity::class.java)
            intent1.putExtra(ImagePickActivity.IS_NEED_CAMERA, false)
            intent1.putExtra(Constant.MAX_NUMBER, 1)
            intent1.putExtra(BaseActivity.IS_NEED_FOLDER_LIST, false)
            startActivityForResult(intent1, Constant.REQUEST_CODE_PICK_VIDEO)
        }
```

ovverride onActivityResult(),

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (data != null) {
            try {
                imageBase64.clear()
                when (requestCode) {
                    AppConstants.REQUEST_CODE_PICK_VIDEO -> {
                        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                            val list = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra<VideoFile>(AppConstants.RESULT_PICK_VIDEO)
                            for (item in list) {
                                imageBase64.add(File(item.path))
                                FILE_TYPE = 2
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
```

create surveyImagesParts array of multipart,

```
val surveyImagesParts: Array<MultipartBody.Part?> = arrayOfNulls(imageBase64.size)
                for (index in imageBase64.indices) {
                    surveyImagesParts[index] = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
                        "message", imageBase64[index].name,
                        RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), imageBase64[index])
                    )
                }
```

pass surveyImagesParts in api call...
hope it will help you...!

Answer (score 0):

The picking part is not the problem, you are getting a URI back. The problem is by default a path is meaningless as you won't be able to access it.

MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA

> This constant was deprecated in API level 29.
>   Apps may not have filesystem permissions to directly access this path. Instead of trying to open this path directly, apps should use ContentResolver#openFileDescriptor(Uri, String) to gain access.

See
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html#DATA

Even if you were able to get a path, then by default you would not have permission to use it, you need to use `ContentResolver#openFileDescriptor(Uri, String)` to gain access.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#openFileDescriptor(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String)

I suggest you read https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/external-scoped to work with storage on the latest API

Updated: Added Example of how to handle the result of the `Intent` call and get a Java `FileDescriptor` which can be passed to most Java IO operations.

```java
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);

        Uri uri = null;

        // The `requestCode` was `1` in the code in the question
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (resultData != null) {
                uri = resultData.getData();
                try {
                    // Open for Read
                    ParcelFileDescriptor pfd =
                            this.getContentResolver().
                                    openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");

                    FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = pfd.getFileDescriptor();

                    // Now do something fileDescriptor like read the input Stream
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream =
                            new FileInputStream(
                                    fileDescriptor);

                    ....


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Do something with Exceptions
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Updated to add some example code on how to get a `FileDescriptor`

Comment: Thank you again, the file is supposed to be a video, can i write those bytes to a new file (copy)?

Comment: Yes you can write files but depending on where you want to save it you might need to use `MediaStore` or `Storage Access Framework` with `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` But again you won't have access to the path with these methods

Comment: Im gonna save it to getExternalFilesDir(). How can i do it?

Comment: I suggest you ask another question as writing files is out scope of this question

Answer (score 0):

Use below permssion in manifest file and if your device is marshmallow   and above then give runtime permission also.

```
         <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```